# Angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Have a function i want to test here is what i have so far

```
it('should push Image to URLs Array', () => {
    const files = new File(['sdfsd'], 'filename', { type: 'image/jpg' });

    component.getImage(files);

    expect(component.URLs.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Here is the function trying to test. it fails because is counting on an event, how do i get around this

```
 getImage(file: File): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        const url = event.target.result;
        this.URLs.push(url);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `FileReader` instance is completely enclosed in your method, there is no way for you to get access to it and fire off the `onload()` method.

One option might be to return the `FileReader` reference from the method.

```
 getImage(file: File): FileReader {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        const url = event.target.result;
        this.URLs.push(url);
    };
    return reader;
}
```

Then your test would be like this:

```
it('should push Image to URLs Array', () => {
    const files = new File(['sdfsd'], 'filename', { type: 'image/jpg' });

    const reader = component.getImage(files);
    reader.onload({target: { result: 'someUrl'}}); // Mock event created here

    expect(component.URLs.length).toBe(1);
});
```

A second option might be to not create FileReader directly, but use a factory or service to create it.  That way you can spy on the create method and return your own object.

Some factory method, for simplicity in the component:

```
createFileReader(): FileReader {
  return new FileReader();
}
```

getImage() would change:

```
 getImage(file: File): void {
    const reader = this.createFileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        const url = event.target.result;
        this.URLs.push(url);
    };
}
```

And the test might be like this:

```
it('should push Image to URLs Array', () => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    spyOn(component, 'createFileReader').and.return(reader);
    const files = new File(['sdfsd'], 'filename', { type: 'image/jpg' });

    const reader = component.getImage(files);
    reader.onload({target: { result: 'someUrl'}}); // Mock event created here

    expect(component.URLs.length).toBe(1);
});
```

If we new the internal details of the `FileReader` class and how `onload` is created / dispatched; it is entirely possible you can trigger it with a reference to an internal Observer from the Observable.  But, I'll refrain from writing out a solution for that since it is goes into a lot of speculation based on code you didn't share.